# How to disable Google Chrome Dark Mode?

Tags: macos, google-chrome

How do I disable the Google Chrome dark mode, but still keep using the dark mode appearance for the OS?

Up until today, Google Chrome was still the white material design. Now when I open it, I get the dark theme.

I can make it white again if I change the system appearance to white, but I like the dark theme for the OS.

I've searched `chrome://flags` and didn't see anything. I've also looked through the settings in Chrome and didn't find anything either.

Any ideas of why it suddenly changed, and how to change it back?

**Chrome Version**: 73.0.3683.86 (Official Build) (64-bit)

**macOS Version**: 10.14.3 (18D109)

> Dark Mode

[image]

> Light Mode

[image]

Answer (score 31, accepted):

#### Use Command

```
defaults write com.google.Chrome NSRequiresAquaSystemAppearance -bool Yes
```

run this in Terminal will do.

#### Disable dark mode of other app

If you want to disable the dark mode of other application
you'll need to get the Bundle Identifier first.

```
osascript -e 'id of app "<App Name>"'
```

This will get the Bundle Identifier. Use the following command to disable dark mod of it.

```
defaults write <Bundle Identifier> NSRequiresAquaSystemAppearance -bool Yes
```

If you want to enable the dark mode of it again

```
defaults delete <Bundle Identifier> NSRequiresAquaSystemAppearance
```

will do.

Comment: The first command worked right away for me - in case you installed a design (like me), visit the settings page, go to design and check "reset to defaults", then the changes will take effect.

Comment: @FlorianMüller worked for me as well. Use the command, restart Chrome and the changes will take effect.

Comment: for canary it's `defaults write com.google.Chrome.canary NSRequiresAquaSystemAppearance -bool Yes`

Comment: Great, thanks. Needed it to turn it off for Iron/Chromium: `defaults write org.chromium.Chromium NSRequiresAquaSystemAppearance -bool YES`

Answer (score 0):

If you want to disable google chrome dark mode while using dark system mode setting then you can do it very easily.

In **MacOs** run in terminal:

```
defaults write com.google.Chrome NSRequiresAquaSystemAppearance -bool YES
```

In **Windows** add the suffix in the target in shortcut properties

```
"C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\Chrome\Application\chrome.exe" --disable-features=DarkMode
```

Source https://www.techllog.com/2019/05/how-to-disable-chromes-dark-mode/

Comment: Note: It's perfectly fine to occasionallly link to your own web site. However, you *must* disclose your affiliation in your answers. See: https://superuser.com/help/promotion

Comment: The suggested solution for Windows doesn't seem to work on Chrome 79 and Windows 10 1909.

Comment: Yes the solution doesn't work for Windows 10 [as of Chrome version 75+](https://techdows.com/2019/05/disable-dark-mode-in-google-chrome-only-but-not-for-windows-10.html#comment-189977).